# TypeORM errors with fs, buffer and stream

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript

My name is George and I'm a first-timer programmer in angular and I have got problems with **Typescript** and **TypeORM**.

When I compile the code, give me this errors

> node_modules/typeorm/driver/mongodb/MongoConnectionOptions.d.ts(53,33): error TS2580: Cannot find name 'Buffer'. Do you need to install type definitions for node? Try `npm i @types/node` and then add `node` to the types field in your tsconfig.
>
> node_modules/typeorm/driver/mongodb/MongoConnectionOptions.d.ts(58,33): error TS2580: Cannot find name 'Buffer'. Do you need to install type definitions for node? Try `npm i @types/node` and then add `node` to the types field in your tsconfig.
>
> node_modules/typeorm/driver/mongodb/MongoConnectionOptions.d.ts(63,32): error TS2580: Cannot find name 'Buffer'. Do you need to install type definitions for node? Try `npm i @types/node` and then add `node` to the types field in your tsconfig.
>
> node_modules/typeorm/driver/mongodb/MongoConnectionOptions.d.ts(68,33): error TS2580: Cannot find name 'Buffer'. Do you need to install type definitions for node? Try `npm i @types/node` and then add `node` to the types field in your tsconfig.
>
> node_modules/typeorm/driver/mongodb/typings.d.ts(92,13): error TS2580: Cannot find name 'Buffer'. Do you need to install type definitions for node? Try `npm i @types/node` and then add `node` to the types field in your tsconfig.
>
> node_modules/typeorm/driver/mongodb/typings.d.ts(294,19): error TS2580: Cannot find name 'Buffer'. Do you need to install type definitions for node? Try `npm i @types/node` and then add `node` to the types field in your tsconfig.
>
> node_modules/typeorm/driver/mongodb/typings.d.ts(298,15): error TS2580: Cannot find name 'Buffer'. Do you need to install type definitions for node? Try `npm i @types/node` and then add `node` to the types field in your tsconfig.
>
> node_modules/typeorm/driver/mongodb/typings.d.ts(302,14): error TS2580: Cannot find name 'Buffer'. Do you need to install type definitions for node? Try `npm i @types/node` and then add `node` to the types field in your tsconfig.
>
> node_modules/typeorm/driver/mongodb/typings.d.ts(306,15): error TS2580: Cannot find name 'Buffer'. Do you need to install type definitions for node? Try `npm i @types/node` and then add `node` to the types field in your tsconfig.
>
> node_modules/typeorm/driver/mongodb/typings.d.ts(365,19): error TS2580: Cannot find name 'Buffer'. Do you need to install type definitions for node? Try `npm i @types/node` and then add `node` to the types field in your tsconfig.
>
> node_modules/typeorm/driver/mongodb/typings.d.ts(369,15): error TS2580: Cannot find name 'Buffer'. Do you need to install type definitions for node? Try `npm i @types/node` and then add `node` to the types field in your tsconfig.
>
> node_modules/typeorm/driver/mongodb/typings.d.ts(373,14): error TS2580: Cannot find name 'Buffer'. Do you need to install type definitions for node? Try `npm i @types/node` and then add `node` to the types field in your tsconfig.
>
> node_modules/typeorm/driver/mongodb/typings.d.ts(377,15): error TS2580: Cannot find name 'Buffer'. Do you need to install type definitions for node? Try `npm i @types/node` and then add `node` to the types field in your tsconfig.
>
> node_modules/typeorm/driver/mongodb/typings.d.ts(416,19): error TS2580: Cannot find name 'Buffer'. Do you need to install type definitions for node? Try `npm i @types/node` and then add `node` to the types field in your tsconfig.
>
> node_modules/typeorm/driver/mongodb/typings.d.ts(420,15): error TS2580: Cannot find name 'Buffer'. Do you need to install type definitions for node? Try `npm i @types/node` and then add `node` to the types field in your tsconfig.
>
> node_modules/typeorm/driver/mongodb/typings.d.ts(424,14): error TS2580: Cannot find name 'Buffer'. Do you need to install type definitions for node? Try `npm i @types/node` and then add `node` to the types field in your tsconfig.
>
> node_modules/typeorm/driver/mongodb/typings.d.ts(428,15): error TS2580: Cannot find name 'Buffer'. Do you need to install type definitions for node? Try `npm i @types/node` and then add `node` to the types field in your tsconfig.
>
> node_modules/typeorm/driver/mongodb/typings.d.ts(1591,25): error TS2580: Cannot find name 'Buffer'. Do you need to install type definitions for node? Try `npm i @types/node` and then add `node` to the types field in your tsconfig.
>
> node_modules/typeorm/driver/mongodb/typings.d.ts(1636,45): error TS2580: Cannot find name 'Buffer'. Do you need to install type definitions for node? Try `npm i @types/node` and then add `node` to the types field in your tsconfig.
>
> node_modules/typeorm/driver/mongodb/typings.d.ts(1647,19): error TS2580: Cannot find name 'Buffer'. Do you need to install type definitions for node? Try `npm i @types/node` and then add `node` to the types field in your tsconfig.
>
> node_modules/typeorm/driver/mongodb/typings.d.ts(4233,34): error TS2580: Cannot find name 'Buffer'. Do you need to install type definitions for node? Try `npm i @types/node` and then add `node` to the types field in your tsconfig.
>
> node_modules/typeorm/driver/mongodb/typings.d.ts(4317,21): error TS2580: Cannot find name 'Buffer'. Do you need to install type definitions for node? Try `npm i @types/node` and then add `node` to the types field in your tsconfig.
>
> node_modules/typeorm/driver/mongodb/typings.d.ts(4478,34): error TS2580: Cannot find name 'Buffer'. Do you need to install type definitions for node? Try `npm i @types/node` and then add `node` to the types field in your tsconfig.
>
> node_modules/typeorm/driver/mongodb/typings.d.ts(4526,21): error TS2580: Cannot find name 'Buffer'. Do you need to install type definitions for node? Try `npm i @types/node` and then add `node` to the types field in your tsconfig.
>
> node_modules/typeorm/driver/mongodb/typings.d.ts(4595,34): error TS2580: Cannot find name 'Buffer'. Do you need to install type definitions for node? Try `npm i @types/node` and then add `node` to the types field in your tsconfig.
>
> node_modules/typeorm/driver/mongodb/typings.d.ts(4627,21): error TS2580: Cannot find name 'Buffer'. Do you need to install type definitions for node? Try `npm i @types/node` and then add `node` to the types field in your tsconfig.
>
> node_modules/typeorm/platform/PlatformTools.d.ts(2,28): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'fs'.
>
> node_modules/typeorm/platform/PlatformTools.d.ts(4,36): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'stream'.
>
> node_modules/typeorm/platform/PlatformTools.d.ts(38,44): error TS2580: Cannot find name 'Buffer'. Do you need to install type definitions for node? Try `npm i @types/node` and then add `node` to the types field in your tsconfig.**

this is my tsconfig file

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
  "lib": [
     "es5",
     "es6",
     "dom"
  ], 
  "target": "es5",      
  "module": "commonjs",
  "moduleResolution": "node",
  "outDir": "./build",
  "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
  "experimentalDecorators": true,
  "sourceMap": true,
  "types": [
     "node"
  ],
  "typeRoots": ["node_modules/@types"]
  
  },
 "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
  ]
}
```

Why this error?

Answer (score 4):

I had a very similar error with an Ionic/Angular 7 and AWS amplify project. Here is a part of the error output:

```
...
[ng] ERROR in node_modules/aws-sdk/clients/acm.d.ts(133,37): error TS2580: Cannot find name 'Buffer'. Do you need to install type definitions for node? Try `npm i @types/node`.
[ng] node_modules/aws-sdk/clients/acm.d.ts(135,38): error TS2580: Cannot find name 'Buffer'. Do you need to install type definitions for node? Try `npm i @types/node`.
[ng] node_modules/aws-sdk/clients/acm.d.ts(469,32): error TS2580: Cannot find name 'Buffer'. Do you need to install type definitions for node? Try `npm i @types/node`.
[ng] node_modules/aws-sdk/clients/acm.d.ts(471,32): error TS2580: Cannot find name 'Buffer'. Do you need to install type definitions for node? Try `npm i @types/node`.
[ng] node_modules/aws-sdk/clients/acmpca.d.ts(283,37): error TS2580: Cannot find name 'Buffer'. Do you need to install type definitions for node? Try `npm i @types/node`.
[ng] node_modules/aws-sdk/clients/acmpca.d.ts(285,38): error TS2580: Cannot find name 'Buffer'. Do you need to install type definitions for node? Try `npm i @types/node`.
[ng] node_modules/aws-sdk/clients/acmpca.d.ts(353,25): error TS2580: Cannot find name 'Buffer'. Do you need to install type definitions for node? Try `npm i @types/node`.
[ng] node_modules/aws-sdk/clients/apigateway.d.ts(1150,23): error TS2580: Cannot find name 'Buffer'. Do you need to install type definitions for node? Try `npm i @types/node`.
[ng] node_modules/aws-sdk/clients/appsync.d.ts(248,23): error TS2580: Cannot find name 'Buffer'. Do you need to install type definitions for node? Try `npm i @types/node`.
[ng] node_modules/aws-sdk/clients/clouddirectory.d.ts(1571,38): error TS2580: Cannot find name 'Buffer'. Do you need to install type definitions for node? Try `npm i @types/node`.
[ng] node_modules/aws-sdk/clients/cloudsearchdomain.d.ts(7,24): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'stream'.
...
```

Unfortunately following the instructions that the error suggested was not my solution.
Instead I had to edit the `tsconfig.app.json` file and totally remove the empty types `"types": []`

Thus it used to be like this:

```
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../out-tsc/app",
    "types": []
  },
  "exclude": [
    "test.ts",
    "**/*.spec.ts"
  ]
}
```

and became like this:

```
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../out-tsc/app"
  },
  "exclude": [
    "test.ts",
    "**/*.spec.ts"
  ]
}
```

If you have entries in the **types array** then there is no problem and you shouldn't have the previously described error.

This comes up when the array is empty.

Comment: @OP basically the empty `"types": []` in `tsconfig.app.json` can overwrite `tsconfig.json` which is why deleting `"types": []` works. Alternatively put types directly in `tsconfig.app.json` rather than in `tsconfig.json`

Answer (score 3):

try like this in tsconfig.app.json

```
{
"extends": "../tsconfig.json",
"compilerOptions": {
"outDir": "../out-tsc/app",
"types": [
  "node"
 ],
},
"exclude": [
 "test.ts",
 "**/*.spec.ts"
]}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are getting the errors because you are missing the declaration files. You need these files if you want to program in Typescript.

As the errors suggest, you can get these files by typing `npm install @types/node`.

**Update**

According to this: [App fails to build - Buffer not found #4487](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/4487#issuecomment-515071405)

You may have to add `"node"` to your `"types"` in tsconfig, like so:

```
  "compilerOptions": {
    [...]
    "types": ["node"]
  },
```

Comment: If you could show us some of your code we could take a look at it. You may still have problems because you are missing an import.

Comment: that doesn't work at all. neither install, nor reinstall - I have the same error with mongoDb that I don't need - typeorm takes all the stuff and doesn't care do you need it or not.

node_modules/typeorm/driver/mongodb/MongoConnectionOptions.d.ts:74:32 - error TS2591: Cannot find name 'Buffer'. Do you need to install type definitions for node? Try `npm i @types/node` and then add `node` to the types field in your tsconfig.

Comment: Adding  "types": ["node"] to compiler options made all the difference for me.